# Call executeQueryAsync method second time gives first time result

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

In the code I tried to get the data from 2 different lists. Input of the second query will be done after executing first list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchButton").click(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function getData() {
            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var SearchItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

            var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('All Dictionary items');

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + SearchItem + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
                '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
                '</view>');

            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

            ctx.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(Title, Id,SL,Description,Type1)');
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(

            function (sender, args) {
                var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    listItemInfoID = oListItem.get_item('SL').toString();
                    listItemInfo = oListItem.get_item('Type1').toString() + '  ' + oListItem.get_item('SL').toString(); //for searching next list

                    itemDescription = oListItem.get_item('Description').toString();
                }
                var desp = itemDescription.toString();
                var despCorrection = desp.replace("</font>", " ");
                despCorrection = despCorrection.substring(35);
                document.getElementById('Descriptions').value = despCorrection;
                document.getElementById('SearchedItem').value = listItemInfo.toString();
                alert('here' + listItemInfoID);

            },

            function (sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            });


        }, "sp.js");

        alert('start new');
        var ContextForRelatedItem = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oListForRelationItem = ContextForRelatedItem.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RelationWithIds');
        var camlQueryForRelatedItem = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQueryForRelatedItem.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Word_SL_No\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + listItemInfoID + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
            '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
            '</view>');
        alert('after query');
        this.collListItemForRelationItem = oListForRelationItem.getItems(camlQueryForRelatedItem);
        ContextForRelatedItem.load(this.collListItemForRelationItem, 'Include(Title, Id,Linked_To,Relation_No)');
        alert('after load');
        ContextForRelatedItem.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            alert('in execute');
            var listItemEnumerator2 = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            document.getElementById('relation1item').value = '';
            document.getElementById('relation2item').value = '';
            while (listItemEnumerator2.moveNext()) {
                var oListItemForRelation = listItemEnumerator2.get_current();
                alert('in while');
                listItemInfoForRelationItem = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Relation_No').toString(); //This alert is not getting triggered.
                alert('in here jyfkufkuyfbjh' + listItemInfoForRelationItem.toString() + 'here');
                relatedItems = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Linked_To');
            }
            alert('values are' + '\n' + relatedItems.toString());
            alert('fine');
        },function (sender, args) { 
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Alerts are getting triggered before    `oListItemForRelation.get_item('Relation_No').toString()`. If I put `oListItemForRelation.get_item('Description').toString()` then the alert gets triggered and the value of previous list returned.

Please help. Please advise me if the approach is wrong. I have to pass a value from one column of a list to another list.

Comment: Hi Rahul, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. I don't have time to look at this right now so if now one else does by the time I do I will get back to it. I also just prettified your code so it is more readable.

Comment: Looks like the code snippet is incomplete - you are missing some lines after the last line.

Comment: Hi James, I just leave the below code end...    },function (sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
      });
    
    
         
        });
    });

Comment: Any Update? hugh?

Answer (score 1):

Working with JavaScript, Ajax and the JSOM involves a lot of async calls and call-backs. What you are doing right now is that you are firing the first query and without waiting for it to finish, you are firing the second query.

Note that the first query will be finished and then the success (or failure) callback will be called. So all the code you want to execute after the first query is finished needs to be included in the callback function of the first query.

This code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#SearchButton").click(function () {
         ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function getData() {
             var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
             var SearchItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

             var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('All Dictionary items');

             var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
             camlQuery.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + SearchItem + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
                 '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
                 '</view>');

             this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

             ctx.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(Title, Id,SL,Description,Type1)');
             ctx.executeQueryAsync(

             function (sender, args) {
                 var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                     var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                     listItemInfoID = oListItem.get_item('SL').toString();
                     listItemInfo = oListItem.get_item('Type1').toString() + '  ' + oListItem.get_item('SL').toString(); //for searching next list

                     itemDescription = oListItem.get_item('Description').toString();
                 }
                 var desp = itemDescription.toString();
                 var despCorrection = desp.replace("</font>", " ");
                 despCorrection = despCorrection.substring(35);
                 document.getElementById('Descriptions').value = despCorrection;
                 document.getElementById('SearchedItem').value = listItemInfo.toString();
                 alert('here' + listItemInfoID);

                 alert('start new');

                 var ContextForRelatedItem = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                 var oListForRelationItem = ContextForRelatedItem.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RelationWithIds');
                 var camlQueryForRelatedItem = new SP.CamlQuery();
                 camlQueryForRelatedItem.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Word_SL_No\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + listItemInfoID + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
                     '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
                     '</view>');
                 alert('after query');
                 this.collListItemForRelationItem = oListForRelationItem.getItems(camlQueryForRelatedItem);
                 ContextForRelatedItem.load(this.collListItemForRelationItem, 'Include(Title, Id,Linked_To,Relation_No)');
                 alert('after load');
                 ContextForRelatedItem.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
                     alert('in execute');
                     var listItemEnumerator2 = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                     document.getElementById('relation1item').value = '';
                     document.getElementById('relation2item').value = '';
                     while (listItemEnumerator2.moveNext()) {
                         var oListItemForRelation = listItemEnumerator2.get_current();
                         alert('in while');
                         listItemInfoForRelationItem = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Relation_No').toString(); //This alert is not getting triggered.
                         alert('in here jyfkufkuyfbjh' + listItemInfoForRelationItem.toString() + 'here');
                         relatedItems = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Linked_To');
                     }
                     alert('values are' + '\n' + relatedItems.toString());
                     alert('fine');
                     },

                     function (sender, args) {
                         alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                     });


         }, "sp.js");


        },function (sender, args) { alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option when making an async call that depends on another async call is to use [`jQuery.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SearchButton').click(function () {
        function getData() {
            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            getFirstItem(ctx).then(function () { // d.resolve will call this function
                alert('start new');

                var oListForRelationItem = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RelationWithIds');
                var camlQueryForRelatedItem = new SP.CamlQuery();
                camlQueryForRelatedItem.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Word_SL_No\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + listItemInfoID + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
                    '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
                    '</view>');
                alert('after query');
                this.collListItemForRelationItem = oListForRelationItem.getItems(camlQueryForRelatedItem);
                ctx.load(this.collListItemForRelationItem, 'Include(Title, Id,Linked_To,Relation_No)');
                alert('after load');
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                    alert('in execute');
                    var listItemEnumerator2 = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                    document.getElementById('relation1item').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('relation2item').value = '';
                    while (listItemEnumerator2.moveNext()) {
                        var oListItemForRelation = listItemEnumerator2.get_current();
                        alert('in while');
                        listItemInfoForRelationItem = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Relation_No').toString(); //This alert is not getting triggered.
                        alert('in here jyfkufkuyfbjh' + listItemInfoForRelationItem.toString() + 'here');
                        relatedItems = oListItemForRelation.get_item('Linked_To');
                    }
                    alert('values are' + '\n' + relatedItems.toString());
                    alert('fine');
                }, function(sender, args) {
                    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                });
            }, function(error) { // d.reject will call this function
                alert(error);
            }); // an optional third function can be added for d.notify for progress updates
        }
    });
});
function getFirstItem(ctx) {
    var d = $.Deferred(),
        SearchItem = document.getElementById('item').value,
        oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('All Dictionary items'),
        camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<view><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + SearchItem + '</Value></Eq></Where>' +
        '</Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit>' +
        '</view>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    ctx.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(Title, Id,SL,Description,Type1)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfoID = oListItem.get_item('SL').toString();
            listItemInfo = oListItem.get_item('Type1').toString() + '  ' + oListItem.get_item('SL').toString(); //for searching next list
            itemDescription = oListItem.get_item('Description').toString();
        }
        var desp = itemDescription.toString();
        var despCorrection = desp.replace("</font>", " ");
        despCorrection = despCorrection.substring(35);
        document.getElementById('Descriptions').value = despCorrection;
        document.getElementById('SearchedItem').value = listItemInfo.toString();
        alert('here' + listItemInfoID);
        d.resolve();    // You can also return the necessary items here instead of using global variables
    }, function(sender, args) {
        d.reject('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```